# Regression vs ANOVA interpretation

Tags: regression, anova

Lets say I have a factor called cognitive load that has 3 levels (low, medium, high) and I want to determine how load levels can affect reaction time on some task

There are at least 2 ways that I could conduct this test.

The first would be a one way ANOVA with a single 3 level factor. After running this test I find that the main effect of this factor is not significant. I was always taught that without a significant main effect you shouldn't/dont need to test the differences between each of the groups/levels

The second way is to dummy code the factor and treat it as a regression, predicting reaction time from the 2 generated dummy variables. If I treat low load as my reference group, then my dummy variables would capture the difference between low/medium and low/high. When I conduct this analysis I find that one of my coefficients is significant (e.g. high is significantly different from low load)

So this situation leads to 2 different interpretations of the results. On the one hand I dont have a significant effect of the factor overall, but upon looking at group differences with regression I find something interesting

Which technique should actually be followed? Should I be looking at group differences in ANOVA despite the lack of a significant main effect?

Comment: Read this  http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/why-anova-and-linear-regression-are-the-same-analysis/ What are you focusing in your study? If cognitive load ANOVA is sufficient, but if it is the cognitive load levels I will use regression.